# SQL statement to determine primary computer for an assigned user based on login count

Tags: sql, count, max, case

I'm trying to have a SQL statement to determine primary computer for an assigned user based on login count. I have data and trying to determine the correct logic.

1. Users can have multiple machines, but only one primary.
2. The highest number of logons becomes the primary machine.
3. Win7 and Win10 assigned to the same user with most logons are both primary machines.

The data:

```
PreviouslyloggedHistory | LogonCount | ComputerName |  OS  | AssetAssigned
user1                   |     31     |  computer1   |  W7  | user1
user5                   |     1      |  computer1   |  W7  | user1
user2                   |     1      |  computer2   |  W7  | user2  
user2                   |     28     |  computer2   |  W7  | user2  
user3                   |     1      |  computer2   |  W7  | user2 
user4                   |     1      |  computer3   |  W10 | user2
user5                   |     1      |  computer3   |  W10 | user2
user2                   |     3      |  computer2   |  W7  | user2
user5                   |     1      |  computer4   |  W10 | user6
user6                   |     1      |  computer4   |  W10 | user6
user7                   |     1      |  computer4   |  W10 | user6
user6                   |     3      |  computer5   |  W10 | user6
user5                   |     1      |  computer4   |  W10 | user6
user6                   |     1      |  computer4   |  W10 | user6
user7                   |     1      |  computer4   |  W10 | user6
user5                   |     1      |  computer4   |  W10 | user6
user6                   |    22      |  computer6   |  W7  | user6
user6                   |     1      |  computer5   |  W10 | user6
user6                   |     1      |  computer4   |  W10 | user6
user7                   |     1      |  computer4   |  W10 | user6
user6                   |     7      |  computer5   |  W10 | user6
```

Here's a query I have tried. I still get a lot of results where machines are marked as primary for more then 1 machine of the same OS.  I cannot figure out how to filter out low logon counts from the query for the same machine name.

```
select *,
CASE
 WHEN [PreviouslyloggedHistory] = [AssetAssigned] THEN 'Primary'
 WHEN [PreviouslyloggedHistory] != [AssetAssigned] THEN 'Secondary'
 ELSE 'Unknown'
End 'TagIt'
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY [AssetAssigned] DESC
```

Comment: Have you tried to write the query yourself yet? Take a shot at writing the query yourself, then if you are still having trouble, post your code and we can help you.

Comment: Can you please post some of that code and we can take a look at it?

Comment: Added  code into the post

Comment: Can there be entries for the same computer with different OS? If so, does that mean its OS was changed or that there are multiple OS installed on it? I.e.: If I see user A used computer #1 ten times with WIN7 and ten times with WIN10 and computer #2 twenty times with WIN7, is this two primary computers (#1 WIN10, #2 WIN7) or just one (#2 WIN7)?

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using? Ranking is much simpler as of MySQL 8.

Comment: How exactly is the result supposed to look at? A list of user + primary computer, so sometimes one row for a user, sometimes two? Or how else? Please show the expected result in your request, just like you are showing the log table rows already.

Comment: I’m using SQL management studio 2017. The result should just have extra column in the same report I Tag I that shows primary or secondary for owners ONLY. All other users that had logged on must be stripped out. OWNER I LOGON COUNTS I OS I TAG

Comment: Same user (example user6) can have win 7 and win 10 as a primary computers as long as he is the asset owner and the with the most logon attempts. Also the same user logged on to another W7 machine with 1 logon attempt and he is an owner; that should be tagged as a secondary. Other users with login entires with a computer name must be removed from the report. If asset owner has another 2 or 3 win7 or win10 machines, they should be classified as secondary machines based on logon counts.

Comment: Let's see if I understand this correctly. You want the same list as shown in your request, only with an added column that either shows 'primary' or 'secondary` per row. But then, you also want to remove all rows where a user uses a secondary computer that's another user's primary computer? And then you can tell somehow whether a user is the computer's owner? How? Why are there two user columns in your data anyway? And you haven't answered my Question "Can there be entries for the same computer with different OS?" and its follow-up questions.

Comment: SQL management studio 2017 is just a platform where you can manage various DBMS. Which are you using? MySQL (which I supposed because of the mysqli tag, but that's PHP and you are not using PHP, are you?) or SQL Server or yet another DBMS? Your non-standard syntax (the brackets) suggests you are using T-SQL (SQL Server).

Comment: Correct, using SQL server. 
1. I want the same list as shown
2. Add extra TAG column that either shows 'primary' or 'secondary` per row. 
3. Remove all rows with other users logging in to asset OWNER’s machines (prim or secondary)
4. 1st column is a history of users logged into the machine. AssetAssigned column is the owner of the machine. If Logged on user same as asset owner = asset owner prim or secondary machine based on logon counts
5. You cannot have 2 same names for the computer with diff OS. Just the owner

Comment: So first reduce with `where login_user = asset_user` in order to only see the users loggin into their own computers (point 3). Then count per user and computer. Highest count per user is 'primary', lower count is 'secondary'. But if for one user and OS there are two primary computers, we choose one of them arbitrarily to stay 'primary' and the other becomes 'secondary'. Yes?

Comment: Yes. that’s correct.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to keep the rows, we use analytic functions to aggregate over a user's rows.

Steps:

1. Apply a `WHERE` clause to only see users logging into their own computers.
2. Add a count per user and computer to see how often the user logged into that computer.
3. Compare with the maximum count per user to mark the primary computer(s)
4. Additionally rank the rows per user and OS in order to only pick one computer per OS as primary.

The query:

```
with counted as
(
  select 
    asset_user, computername, os, logoncount,
    sum(logoncount) over (partition by asset_user, computername) as cnt
  from mytable
  where login_user = asset_user
)
select
  asset_user, computername, os, logoncount,
  case when cnt = max(cnt) over(partition by asset_user)
        and rank() over (partition by asset_user, os order by cnt desc, computername) = 1
         then 'primary'
         else 'secondary'
       end as priority
from counted
order by asset_user, priority, os;
```

Result:

```
+------------+--------------+-----+------------+-----------+
| asset_user | computername | os  | logoncount | priority  |
+------------+--------------+-----+------------+-----------+
| user1      | computer1    | W7  | 31         | primary   |
| user2      | computer2    | W7  | 1          | primary   |
| user2      | computer2    | W7  | 28         | primary   |
| user2      | computer2    | W7  | 3          | primary   |
| user6      | computer6    | W7  | 22         | primary   |
| user6      | computer5    | W10 | 7          | secondary |
| user6      | computer5    | W10 | 3          | secondary |
| user6      | computer5    | W10 | 1          | secondary |
| user6      | computer4    | W10 | 1          | secondary |
| user6      | computer4    | W10 | 1          | secondary |
+------------+--------------+-----+------------+-----------+
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=309ee5ff85d4b863b04f8c40d98527da

Comment: Hi Thorsten, is it possible to have output based on the OS?  For the user 6 has Win7 with the high number of logins and classified correctly as primary, but also user has Win10 "computer5" with 11 logons and shows as secondary and should be a primary. The third "computer4" with low logon counts shows correct as a secondary. Also would it be possible to remove multiple rows with each logoncount and just use the Totalcount instead? select
  asset_user, computername, os, logoncount, cnt as [TotalCount]

Comment: Okay, this is quite a change to your specifications. I suppose, had you added a sample result to your request, you would have noticed yourself that your requirements and expected results don't match. I've added another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your altered specifications under my previous answer shows that you didn't know exactly what result you were after. Such is quite often the cause for wrong queries and this is why we always ask for a sample result in the request. It would have helped us and it probably would have helped you, too, in the first place.

You said you wanted to keep the original rows and you wanted to find the maximal used computer per user and if there were two such computers with the same OS we'd have to pick one arbitrarily. Now it seems you don't want to keep the original rows, but merely show one row per user and computer and mark one computer per user's OS as primary. That is much, much simpler.

Group by user, computer (and its OS), to get the count. Number these results per user and OS ordered by logins to get one primary computer for the pair.

```
select
  asset_user, computername, os, sum(logoncount) as total_logins,
  case when row_number() over (partition by asset_user, os
                               order by sum(logoncount) desc, computername) = 1
    then 'primary'
    else 'secondary'
  end as priority
from mytable
where login_user = asset_user
group by asset_user, computername, os
order by asset_user, priority, os, computername;
```

Result:

```
+------------+--------------+-----+--------------+-----------+
| asset_user | computername | os  | total_logins | priority  |
+------------+--------------+-----+--------------+-----------+
| user1      | computer1    | W7  |           31 | primary   |
| user2      | computer2    | W7  |           32 | primary   |
| user6      | computer5    | W10 |           11 | primary   |
| user6      | computer6    | W7  |           22 | primary   |
| user6      | computer4    | W10 |            3 | secondary |
+------------+--------------+-----+--------------+-----------+
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8ab619f88b8e1adfff81e3d18e0446fe